# issue with a code received within an iframe to run a function

Tags: javascript

[image]

this code has been recieved within `iframe` in order to run a function called `uploadingData(x,y)` in the main window but there is a problem as you can see. I cant get what is wrong!!

Comment: use window.parent.uploadingData

Answer (score 2):

The page within the IFrame is seperate from the main page (the `parent` page). Thus, to call code on the main page from within the IFrame, you have to get the function from the parent of the IFrame, as Diodeus pointed out. That looks like this:

```
window.parent.uploadingData(x,y);
```